# int[] table = new int[10],x; is valid syntax?

Tags: java, arrays, variable-declaration

When I initialize a new array I noticed if I put a `,x` it still compiles. I'm not sure what is happening here.

```
int[] table = new int[10],x;
for(int x=1; x<11; x++){
    System.out.println("Count is: " + x);
}
```

If I try running this it says that x is already defined.  I would never write code in this manner as it would be quite confusing; I'm just curious what x is being defined as.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
int[] table = new int[10],x;
```

is valid syntax because x is just another int[] array variable.

Just like you declare multiple variables of a single type in one line:

```
int a=1,b,c,d,e,f;
```

> If I try running this it says that x is already defined

because you are trying to declare x second time in your for loop under the same scope. In your code i don't see any need of defining x as an array type and you can always define x as int inside the loop just as you did.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense! For some reason I was pondering this for a while.

Answer (score 1):

It's defined as an `int[]` based on the first statement. C-family languages (C, C++, Java, C#, D, …) allow separating same-type declarations with `,`. For a new set of declarations with a different type, terminate the statement with `;` and write a new one (which is basically what you had in the `for` loop already).

Answer (score 0):

Of cause you will get a syntax error.You have defined `x` as an int array at the beginning.So you can not redefined it as    an int variable in `x`'s scope.